How to insert a named subskeleton from another skeleton?
I have a main skeleton and a subskeleton, both defined with define-skeleton. I
would like to insert the subskeleton from the main one, using its name.
(define-skeleton my-subskeleton
  "My subskeleton."
  "Author: "
  "#+author: " str \n _)

(define-skeleton my-skeleton
  "My skeleton."
  "Title: "
  "#+title: " str \n
  ;; anonymous subskeleton, OK
  ("Define macro: " "#+MACRO: " str \n)
  ;; named subskeleton, not OK
  ;; ...
  )

I read the (autotype) Skeleton Language Info manual, but still cannot figure
out how to insert the subskeleton. Here is what I tried with the errors I got.
;; directly put the subskeleton name
;; skeleton-internal-1: Symbol’s value as variable is void: my-subskeleton
(define-skeleton my-skeleton
  "My skeleton."
  "Title: "
  "#+title: " str \n
  ("Define macro: " "#+MACRO: " str \n)
  my-subskeleton)

;; quote the subskeleton name
;; skeleton-internal-1: Symbol’s value as variable is void: my-subskeleton
(define-skeleton my-skeleton
  "My skeleton."
  "Title: "
  "#+title: " str \n
  ("Define macro: " "#+MACRO: " str \n)
  'my-subskeleton)

;; subskeleton name in a list
;; skeleton-internal-1: Lisp nesting exceeds ‘max-lisp-eval-depth’
(define-skeleton my-skeleton
  "My skeleton."
  "Title: "
  "#+title: " str \n
  ("Define macro: " "#+MACRO: " str \n)
  (my-subskeleton))

;; quoted subskeleton name in a list
;; Emacs crashes (30.0.50)
(define-skeleton my-skeleton
  "My skeleton."
  "Title: "
  "#+title: " str \n
  ("Define macro: " "#+MACRO: " str \n)
  ('my-subskeleton))

Also, I noticed that when the *mu4e-main* buffer is alive, the errors no longer
come from skeleton-internal-1 but from mu4e--modeline-quote-and-truncate.

I think the "right" way would be to call my-subskeleton as you do in the second case - after all these are just functions and you would be nesting a function call within another. However, as you note, you get infinite regress: skeleton-internal-1 keeps calling itself recursively. I'm not sure how to make the call bottom out but there is a possible tell in the documentation: Subskeletons are inserted recursively, not once, but as often as the user enters something at the subskeletons interactor.  Thus there must be a ‘str’ in the subskeleton. I don't know what that means though.

@NickD Yes, as in the answer I accepted, we can just call the subskeleton function for its side-effect.

"...we can just call the subskeleton function for its side-effect." - I don't know what that means either. The answer quotes the call which I think means that somebody evaluates that form twice: I believe that's what makes it work, but I haven't dug into the details of define-skeleton to figure out how that is done.

@NickD I believe David's comment below answers your question, it is explained in the Info node I mentioned in the question.

Thanks! Yes, that explains it. It's the entry right before the one I quoted above, but I was too blind to see it. But I'll need to study skeletons some more before I'm comfortable with them.

(define-skeleton my-skeleton
  "My skeleton."
  "Title: "
  "#+title: " str \n
  ("Define macro: " "#+MACRO: " str \n)
  '(my-subskeleton))

The entire call to my-subskeleton is quoted for the side effect is working for me.

+1 - That works for me too, but what do you mean by the last sentence?

I'm using the rule that quoted Lisp expressions are evaluated for their side-effects.  We want to call Lisp expression (my-subskeleton) but we don't want the return value which ends up t.  As noted above Subskeletons are inserted recursively....  An example of this is the ("Define macro: ) subskeleton in the original my-skeleton.  Calling (my-subskeleton) is a Lisp call not a subskeleton.

Ah yes, right in front of my eyes: ‘EXPRESSION      Evaluate following Lisp expression for its side-effect, but prevent      it from being interpreted as a skeleton element. Thanks for the explanation!
